# Can we find a closed form formula for this function?

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I'm interested in this function

$$
h(m,n) = \operatorname{sgn}\Bigl(\lim_{w \to \infty}{\sum_{x_1=1}^{w}\dotsi\sum_{x_u=1}^{w}\dfrac{1}{1 + wp^2(m,n,x_1,\dotsc,x_u)}}\Bigr)
$$

where $p$ is a polynomial in $u+2$ variables and integer coefficients. Can we simplify it to
$$
h(m,n) = \operatorname{sgn}\Bigl(\dfrac{f(m,n)}{g(m,n)}\Bigr)
$$

without the limit?

Comment: What’s $p$? Is $u$ given? Why the parenthesis closes there?

Comment: @AlessandroDellaCorte $p$ is a polynomial with $u$ unknown and a specific degree

Comment: So $m,n,w,u,x_1,\dots,x_u$ are all non-negative integers and $\epsilon$ a real number, aren't they? And is $p$ a polynomial with real coefficients?

Comment: You are asking for the sign of a sum of positive values: and you want to know if at the limit it is zero or 1, is that correct? Basically you are asking if dominated conevergence applies? Well, if the sums are finite for $\epsilon=1$, since the term being summed is monotonous in $\epsilon$, the answer is yes, it is zero, thank you Lebesgue.

Comment: @PietroMajer that's right but $p$ coefficients are integers

Comment: Ok, with the parentheses put in this way it's understandable.

Comment: @username yes, I have to study your second question

Comment: Could you please stop editing your question? It looks like you do not change anything and just want to bump it to the front page.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier sorry, I only edit it 2 times, the first edit was not correct so I removed it

Comment: By editing the question to remove the mention of $\epsilon$, you have made the existing answer invalid.

Comment: @JRN that edit doesn't count, it was on the same day as I asked the question, beside it doesn't change the function and the current answer doesn't answer what I meant to ask

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean $\epsilon$ is a real positive number and $p$ is a real-valued function in $2+u$ variables, you want a limit of a sum of non-negative numbers,
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\sum_{x\in\mathbb N_+^u}\frac{\epsilon^2}{\epsilon^2+p^2(n,m,x)}.$$
For $\epsilon\searrow 0$, each coefficient   converges decreasing either to $1$ or $0$, according whether $p(n,m,x)=0$ or not. Therefore, if the sum is finite for at least one $\epsilon$, by Beppo Levi  the limit is just the number of non-negative integer zeros $x\in\mathbb N_+^u$ of $p(n,m,\cdot\}$; and if $\text{sgn}$ is the usual signum function, the final expression is $1$ or $0$ according whether $p(n,m,\cdot)$ has a zero $x\in\mathbb N_+^u$ or not.

Comment: So everything reduces to checking if the sum is finite for at least one $\epsilon>0$ (hence for all, since each term is concave w.r.to $\epsilon$). If e.g. $p$ is a constant, the sum is infinite for all $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: $p$ is a integer valued function. what I have in mind is whether it can be simplified to $f(m,n)/g(m,n)$ without the limit so my function could have some undefined values

Comment: @PietroMajer You say Beppo-Levi, I say Lebesgue : Potayto/Potahto... : )

Comment: I really mean beppi levi (monotone convergence; no need of finiteness if it was increasing); though lebesgue would also do (dominated convergence)

Comment: The question has been changed; $\epsilon$ is now no longer mentioned. Your answer has become invalid.